# How to properly use Mongoose models?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to save the some information in to `Mongo` with `Mongoose`, but nothing happens… My code is :

```
function User() {
    console.log(_db.version);

    var user_schema = new _db.Schema({ 
        'email': { 'type': String, 'required': true, 'lowercase': true, 'index': { 'unique': true } },
        'password': { 'type': String, 'required': true },
        'name': {'type': String, 'required': true},
        'age': {'type': Date},
    }, {'collection': 'users'});

    var user_model = _db.model('user', user_schema);

    this.createNew = function(name, age) {
        console.log('createNew');

        var new_user = new user_model({'name': name, 'age': age});

        new_user.save(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log('Save function');
        });
    }
}

var user = new User();
user.createNew('Tom', 21);
```

In the result i just get `3.8.1 createNew`.

Comment: new User() instead of User()

Comment: `this` in `this.createNew` won't be what you want if you don't use `new` to create `User`.

Comment: with object creation is everything ok, in the program everything quite differently, the problem is that `new_user.save` doest fire.

Comment: @Kin please mark the answer you think is correct..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you change your approach a bit, try this out:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase': true,
        index: {unique: true},
    },
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    age: {type: Date},
})

UserSchema.statics.createNew = function(email, password, name, age, next) {
    var user = new this({  
        email: email,
        password: password,
        name: name,
        age: age
    })
    user.save(next)
}

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Now you can create a new User by:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User')
User.createNew('tom@gmail.com', 'password', 'Tom', 21, function(err, user) {
    ...
})
```

Added email and password as arguments because the Schema says that they are required.

Comment: This still would not work, since "password" and "email" are required as shubhank srivastava mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you assigning values to email and password fields of the schema.

> required: {Boolean} - If true, creates a validation rule requiring
>   this path be set before saving occurs.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html